# Postcode mapping different countries

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, postal-code

We have a little side project running where we need to create maps of different countries containing postcodes and postcode area boundaries, which are put in a database. Those maps are supposed to be usable for several reports and visual display - through the database entries. 
It appears it needs to be done from scratch (meaning we won’t pay for the data).

I’m completely new to QGIS and georeferencing and searched through several tutorials, but some clues are missing.

So far I have a blank shapefile of a country, which is already georeferenced.
Now what i need to do (from my understanding):

1. Get the post code data and import it (which is hard for countries like    Romania, since there seems to be nothing like tables available for free), **OR** put **only** the post code areas into the map manually.
   -> But how can you do that somewhat accurately? Just using polygons?
2. Make it usable for a database, e.g. using SpatiaLite.

Are there any good resources about the steps of such a specific task?

**edit**: Sorry for causing some confusion. I adjusted the question a little.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Do you already have a map of postcodes that you need to "trace" the boundaries of?

Comment: draw the postcodes? - it will take a long time (that will be more expensive than purchasing the data/license) and postcodes (example UK Postcodes can change every quarter and even renamed)

Comment: I cannot see what your are looking for: post codes and boundaries data? How to make a map of these data? If you're looking after the data, have a look at my answer here: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11362/morocco-post-code-shapefiles

Comment: Slightly edited the question, thanks for the effort so far. 
For now i just need a way to put those post code areas (not every post code, because no more specific data than that is available afaik) into a map (Romania in this example).
I thought of making a polygon for each area and then just put the numbers on top. But I'm still not sure how and if this really is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume you want a map showing postcodes of Romania, using QGIS.

First, get some data: you can get administrative levels polygons from OpenStreetMap. Communes in Romania are represented using the OSM tag admin_level=6, according to this [page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative). You can query the OSM data using the overpass turbo website: use the wizard and type `boundary=administrative and admin_level=6 in Romania`. This results in this query: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/q38. Run the query and export the data as geojson. There are 5336 polygons. I don't know if the data is complete.

Second, make the map (in QGIS): This is a fairly basic thing, but it depends what and how you want to map. Open the geojson layer, display it and label it with addr:postcode or siruta:code (don't know what are the right zip code for Romania). Since there are 1000's of polygons, you need to have a map at a large scale to display the post codes.

Put this data in a database is another story, but I'm sure you'll find information on this website or elsewhere.